# Attribute Error: Nonetype has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex, attributeerror, nonetype

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "redact.py", line 100, in <module>
match = int(re.match(r'\d+', number).group())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

input = (1, 2)(5, 2)(14, 2)(17, 2)(1, 3)(5, 3)(14, 3)(17, 3)(1, 4)(5, 4)(8, 4)(9, 4)(10, 4)(11, 4)(14, 4)(17, 4)(20, 4)(21, 4)(22, 4)(23, 4)(1, 5)(2, 5)(3, 5)(4, 5)(5, 5)(8, 5)(9, 5)(10, 5)(11, 5)(14, 5)(17, 5)(20, 5)(21, 5)(22, 5)(23, 5)(1, 6)(5, 6)(8, 6)(9, 6)(10, 6)(11, 6)(14, 6)(17, 6)(20, 6)(23, 6)(1, 7)(5, 7)(8, 7)(9, 7)(14, 7)(17, 7)(20, 7)(21, 7)(22, 7)(23, 7)(1, 8)(5, 8)(8, 8)(9, 8)(10, 8)(11, 8)(14, 8)(17, 8)(20, 8)(21, 8)(22, 8)(23, 8)

output = >>>error above
This is the error message I am getting after executing the following code:

```
xcoord = []
regex = ur"\b[0-9,]{1,}[,]\s\b"  #regex for x coordinates
result = re.findall(regex,str1)

for number in result: #get x numbers from coordinate
    match = int(re.match(r'\d+', number).group())
    xcoord.append(match) #now got array of numbers for x    
maxValueX = max(xcoord) #biggest x value

ycoord = []
regex = ur"\b[,]\s[0-9,]{1,}\b" #regex for y coordinates
result = re.findall(regex,str1)

for number in result: #get y numbers from coordinate
    match = int(re.match(r'\d+', number).group())
    ycoord.append(match) #now got array of numbers for y
maxValueY = max(ycoord) #biggest y value

print maxValueX 
print maxValueY
```

The string it is searching through is: "5', ', 5', ', 6', ', 3',". On two different online regex generators the above regex works perfectly for the string. Why is it working for the X coordinate but NOT the Y one? The code is exactly the same!

(I am trying to obtain the integers from the string by the way).

Thanks

Comment: By the way, if anyone asks, the first regex of Y or X is perfect and works, it is the second one with the .group() which is causing the problem.

Comment: How is that *"extremely wierd [sic]"*? Evidently, there is no `match` for that `pattern` in `number` - why not `print number` and find out why?

Comment: -1 Surely it's not beyond you to provide a complete program that demonstrates the problem. That way we actually have your input data. Clearly `re.match()` has returned `None`. But your program depends on its input data. Which you have not provided.

Comment: re.match() returns None for some cases

Comment: "print number" gives ", 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4", the regex '\d+' should find the numbers no?

Comment: here is str1 - input data: (17, 7)(20, 7)(21, 7)(22, 7)(23, 7)(1, 8)(5, 8)(8, 8)(9, 8)(10, 8)(11, 8)(14, 8)(17, 8)(20, 8)(21, 8)(22, 8)(23, 8) for you David Heffernan

Comment: Please edit the question to include a complete program that contains the input data. Then we can give you answers that explain why your regex does not match

Comment: done, added input data.

Comment: `re.match()` only finds a match at the start of the string.

Comment: You did not do what I asked. You did not provide compilable code. We have to guess that `str` is actually a string. You omitted quotes. Why is it so hard for you to supply a complete program? I'm sorry to whine on but this is a really important lesson. Once you've learnt it you'll be a much better programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No regex needed:

```
str1 = "(8, 5)(9, 5)(10, 5)(11, 5)(14, 5)(17, 5)(20, 5)(21, 5)(22, 5)(23, 5)(1, 6)(5, 6)(8, 6)(9, 6)(10, 6)(11, 6)(14, 6)(17, 6)(20, 6)(23, 6)(1, 7)(5, 7)(8, 7)(9, 7)(14, 7)(17, 7)(20, 7)(21, 7)(22, 7)(23, 7)(1, 8)(5, 8)(8, 8)(9, 8)(10, 8)(11, 8)(14, 8)(17, 8)(20, 8)(21, 8)(22, 8)(23, 8)"

xcoord = [int(element.split(",")[0].strip()) for element in str1[1:-1].split(")(")]
ycoord = [int(element.split(",")[1].strip()) for element in str1[1:-1].split(")(")]

maxValueX = max(xcoord); maxValueY = max(ycoord)
print maxValueX;
print maxValueY;
```

Comment: perfect, works and cuts my code down! you sir have earned a green tick

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of variable `str1` ???

`re.match(r'\d+', number)` is returning `None` because `number` does not match with your regular expression, review the content of the variable `result` that depends on `str1`.

Each regular expression has to be tested step by step, try some regex web tool like [this](http://www.pythonregex.com/) to test them.

Change your regex to: `regex = "\b([0-9]+)\,\s\b"`

Comment: str1 = (8, 5)(9, 5)(10, 5)(11, 5)(14, 5)(17, 5)(20, 5)(21, 5)(22, 5)(23, 5)(1, 6)(5, 6)(8, 6)(9, 6)(10, 6)(11, 6)(14, 6)(17, 6)(20, 6)(23, 6)(1, 7)(5, 7)(8, 7)(9, 7)(14, 7)(17, 7)(20, 7)(21, 7)(22, 7)(23, 7)(1, 8)(5, 8)(8, 8)(9, 8)(10, 8)(11, 8)(14, 8)(17, 8)(20, 8)(21, 8)(22, 8)(23, 8), I am trying to get the X value as the first number in the brackets and the Y as the second, into seperate arrays as integers.

Comment: Change your regex to: regex = "\b([0-9]+)\,\s\b"

Comment: I have used that exact regex web tool on the strings I have provided, str1 AND result and it still gives the error.

Comment: juankysmith - your solution matches exactly the same as mine. thanks anyway

Comment: No, yours include ","

Answer (score 0):

This will create two lists one with all first elements of and one with all the second.

```
x_cord = map(int,re.findall("(?<=\()\d+",str1))

y_cord= map(int,re.findall("(?<=\,\s)\d+",str1))
x_cord
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 1, 5, 8, 9, 14, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23]

y_cord  
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```